# how to minimize the use of subquery

Tags: sql, t-sql

i have the following tables and i would like to calculate the sales figure. I used some subquery to do it. Can i not using subquery and not using table variable to do it ?

```
TableA, 4 columns - popuplation
pkeyP | population | city | country 
some data
100, 1234, london, UK
101, 2345, oxford, UK
102, 3345, bristol, UK
103, 1256, new york, USA
104, 5424, LA, USA
105, 100, beijing, China

Table B, 4 columns - sales_amount
pkeyA | amount | city | country
some data
200, 105, london, UK
201, 210, oxford, UK
203, 23, new york, USA
204, 54, LA, USA

the city in first table may not exist in second table
```

```
select aa.country, aa.popu, bb.amou from 
    (select sum(population) as popu, country from population group by country) aa
left join 
    (select sum(amount) as amou, country from sales_amount group by countr) bb
on aa.country = bb.country
```

```
subquery 1 will return 
UK, 6924
USA, 6680
China, 100

subquery 2 will return
UK, 315
USA, 77

final result
UK, 6924, 315
USA, 6680, 77,
China, 100, null
```

It is an example. My real query has many small tables like this and i need to do group by first and then join to do final calculation.

i dont want to use subquery because my real table has lot more columns and real query is extreme long. It is very un-readable, very hard to maintain.

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help you.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable approach. Why do you want to change it?

Comment: LIkely, however, you are going to need at least one subquery.

Comment: Why don't you just join all the tables and call one groupby at the end instead always doing a groupby in a subquery? The query optimizer should be smart enough to figure out how to do this efficiently

Comment: @Karl: Because those joins would be many-to-many and the sums would be plain wrong

Answer (score 0):

You could do something as follows to join individual query results into one as follows

```
select aa.country, aa.popu, bb.amou,cc.smou from 
    (select sum(population) as popu, country from population group by country) aa
inner join 
    (select sum(amount) as amou, country from sales_amount group by countr) bb
on aa.country = bb.country inner join
    (select sum(sales) as smou, country from sales_amount group by countr) cc
on bb.country = cc.country
-- inner join ..  so on as you wrote....
```

Comment: This is the same as the original query, just an alternative order of joins, no human being will ever use :-)

Comment: Okay, I don't see any other option to read the results when one wants to combine results from different tables into a single query result! Other than, writing a CTE or creating a View or something as above..

Answer (score 0):

EDIT, ok, well then why not create views where the aggregation is already done, especially if this is information you are frequently going to use. If readability is your main concern then this should help. E.g.:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_aggregated_population AS
SELECT sum(population) AS popu, country 
FROM population GROUP BY country

CREATE VIEW vw_aggregated_sales_amount AS
SELECT sum(amount) AS amou, country 
FROM sales_amount GROUP BY country
```

Followed by

```
SELECT
vw_aggregated_population.country,
popu, 
amou,
FROM vw_aggregated_population
LEFT JOIN vw_aggregated_sales_amount
ON vw_aggregated_population.country=vw_aggregated_sales_amount.country
GROUP BY vw_aggregated_population.country
```

Comment: Because those joins would be many-to-many and the sums would be plain wrong. Additionaly performance would be horrible due to the exploding number of rows.

Comment: Ok, you should maybe state that in your question. See updated answer

Comment: This is obvious, why should you GROUP BY a column which is already UNIQUE?

Comment: You would be surprised how many of those types of things I've seen in SO questions...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `full join` or `group by` with `union all` to get *all* rows in all tables.  Here is an example using the second approach:

```
with p as (
      select sum(population) as population, country
      from population
      group by country
     ),
     sa as (
      select sum(amount) as amount, country
      from sales_amount
      group by country
     ) 
select country, max(population), max(amount)
from ((select country, population, null as amount
       from p
      ) union all
      (select country, null, amount
       from sa
      )
     ) ps
group by country;
```

It should be clear how to expand this for more tables.

Comment: Since many tables are involved, and we are not aware of data size. So, From performance perspective, Which would you prefer? Full join or Union all with group by.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai . . . I put the `union all` approach in because it generalizes more easily.  I'm am not actually sure which would work better in SQL Server.  If you have a large amount of data, it is worth comparing performance.  `FULL JOIN` has some additional overhead compared to other `JOIN`s.  `GROUP BY` also has overhead.  But if you have indexes on `country` in each of the subtables, then the `GROUP BY` should be very reasonable.